# How to convert geojson file into class model in django

Tags: django, django-models, geojson

I have geojson data in the URL. Here is the URL: 
https://publoccityhealthdata.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/chi_boundries.geojson

I need to generate model class for Django using `ogrinspect`
from `django.contrib.gis.db import models`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Go to manage.py folder level.

Step 2: Make sure `django-contrib-gis` is installed.

Step 3: Type this command to the terminal  `python manage.py ogrinspect https://publoccityhealthdata.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/chi_boundries.geojson Neighborhoods --srid=4326 --mapping --multi`

You will get following result:

```
class Neighborhoods(models.Model):
pri_neigh = models.CharField(max_length=0)
sec_neigh = models.CharField(max_length=0)
shape_area = models.CharField(max_length=0)
shape_len = models.CharField(max_length=0)
geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)

# This is an auto-generated Django model module created by ogrinspect.
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

neighborhoods_mapping = {
'pri_neigh': 'pri_neigh',
'sec_neigh': 'sec_neigh',
'shape_area': 'shape_area',
'shape_len': 'shape_len',
'geom': 'MULTIPOLYGON',
}
```